# VB Brackets in Enum?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, syntax, brackets

I'm finding this in some legacy code and just curious what the brackets are for?

```
Public Enum myEnum
    none = 0
    abc = 2
    def = 4
    ghi= 6
    [jkl] = 8
    mno = 9
End Enum
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're not needed in the example you provided, which I assume you have obscured, but the brackets let you specify a name for an enum item that would otherwise conflict with a reserved word.

Answer (score 6):

Brackets are usually used when you want to use a keyword for a variable, classname, function name, or something else where using a keyword would usually be not allowed.  Here is a list of the [vb.net keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/).

Answer (score 0):

If one value of your enum is a reserved word, then you must use square bracket for this value.
Example:

```
Public Enum PersistanceStates
 [New]
 None
 Update  End Enum
```

New is a reserved keyword in VB.NET so I need to use square bracket.