# Difference between [Assembly] & Assembly

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does [String] mean in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198442/what-does-string-mean-in-vb-net)

Dim assem As [Assembly] = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()

Dim assem As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778618/vb-brackets-in-enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square braces in VB.NET are used to allow for literal naming, even if the identifier might be a keyword in VB.NET. Generally, these are more prevalent in generated code, since there's no point in doing it unless the word actually *is* a keyword.

In this case, there is no difference. What square braces allow you to do would be to, say, name a class the same as a keyword in VB.NET. For example,

```
Dim test as [Dim]
```

This would allow you to name your class `Dim`, which would ordinarily give you an error since `Dim` is a keyword.

Likewise, you can use it for variable names:

```
Dim [Dim] as String
```

Here, instead of on the type name, we're using it on the variable name. Same concept.

However, if you're doing this, then it's generally a code smell; it's usually a better idea to find a name that *isn't* a keyword so that people using your class don't *have* to enclose the name in braces.